# Reset UIPickerview after use?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerview that goes from 0-20. I want the users to be forced to select a int between 1 and 20. If the picker is on 0, an alert should pop up. The selection is confirmed with a button press, and same with the alert.
I have done this:

```
pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

This works fine one time. The picker return to 0, but if the next user forgets to select a number, the picker prints whatever the last user had selected, and not 0 that its actually showing.

How can I get the pickerView to understand that it has returned to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the variable used in `didSelectRow` to 0 when button is pressed.
If you have:
 `var chosenPickerViewNumber = Int()`

and to populate the pickerView you have:

```
let pickerViewNumbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
       chosenPickerViewNumber = pickerViewNumbers[row]
    }
```

You can simply do:

```
@IBAction func yourButton(_ sender: UIButton){
     //Do stuff with the pickerView.    
      //Then:    
      chosenPickerViewNumber = 0   
    }
```